# UBUNTU 22.04 LTS tabbed activities

Tags: gnome, tabs

The "Activities" button on the top left of my UBUNTU screen always shows a tab next to it with the current window that is in focus.

Is there a way that I can make ALL windows or specific windows show in the "Activities" tab and for them to be clickable to bring the window to the front of the screen?

I am trying to avoid having to click "Activities" and then visually finding the window (2 of my windows look very similar and I often click the wrong one).

Almost like a way to "Pin" the tab to the "Activities" so that any window can be brought to the front with 1 click.

Example: How would YOU copy-paste text from a document into an excel file for 100 items?

Comment: The last window will be in front when you click the application in the dock. So when copying from a document to a spreadsheet file, it would suffice to click the icon for the document application, copy, then click the icon of the spreadsheet application to paste. However, specifically for copying 100 items, I definitely would work with a clipboard manager - copy 10 items  at once, then switch and paste the 10 items. That only if it is not possible to instead import the data from the document all at once into the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's not exactly visually what you're describing, the core functionality you're talking about - having a horizontal list of open windows always on-screen, so you can activate a window by clicking an entry in that list - would be obtainable pretty easily via the [Window List GNOME extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/602/window-list/).

To get that, you could run `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions` to install that (and several other official ones), and `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager` to install a GUI app to switch Window List and other extensions on/off.

FWIW your example there (to me) has a different answer than the function you're asking about, though - if you need to copy-paste from something into a spreadsheet 100 times, back and forth, I would tile the windows (one on the left half of the screen, one on the right) and <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between the two as needed.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thank you! I will try to test this out tomorrow and post here. The "copy paste" example is just an example - the main problem I seem to have is that I am on remote servers and tabbing often does the wrong screen - so I find using the mouse easier.